# why my for loop isn't looping? It's only giving the same value multiple times?

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Rnm1_list = [] 
coordsA=[]
for a in range(2):
    c1= np.array([0,0])
    c2= np.array([a,0])
    a1= np.array([3/2*a,3**0.5/2*a])
    a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3**0.5/2*a])
    def Rnm_1():
        for n in range(-1,2):
            for m in range(-1,2):
                    Rnm1= c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
                    Rnm1_list.append(Rnm1)
        return Rnm1_list
    coordsA.append(Rnm1_list)
```

In this code, my a isn't changing, it's generating the same array over and over again and I can't understand why?
Can you help me figuring out where is the problem?

I tried range, linspace and I generated an array that has the values, the a is not changing in any of these ways.
I am doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: The problem is what exactly? `coordsA` only contains a bunch of empty lists? That's because you never call `Rnm_1()`.

Comment: You are re-defining `Rnm_1` every time you go through the loop, and you never call it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're aiming at here, but you never call your `Rnm_1` function, or assign `Rnm1_list` to anything other than an empty list.

Comment: why are you defining a function inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The routine defined by

```
def Rnm_1()
```

is never executed

you can run it at the end of its definition:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Rnm1_list = [] 
coordsA=[]
for a in range(2):
    c1= np.array([0,0])
    c2= np.array([a,0])
    a1= np.array([3/2*a,3**0.5/2*a])
    a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3**0.5/2*a])
    def Rnm_1():
        for n in range(-1,2):
            for m in range(-1,2):
                    Rnm1= c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
                    Rnm1_list.append(Rnm1)
        return Rnm1_list
    # Call the routine to populate the required fields
    Rnm_1()
    coordsA.append(Rnm1_list())
```

or just use its content to make it easier to read and also because the variables used are outside "Rnm_1()" scope:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Rnm1_list = [] 
coordsA=[]
for a in range(2):
    c1= np.array([0,0])
    c2= np.array([a,0])
    a1= np.array([3/2*a,3**0.5/2*a])
    a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3**0.5/2*a])
    for n in range(-1,2):
        for m in range(-1,2):
                Rnm1= c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
                Rnm1_list.append(Rnm1)
    coordsA.append(Rnm1_list)
```

Comment: I tried what you recommended but this time I had another problem, it looped twice over the second value of the range, do you have any idea why that happened?

Comment: Try to initialise the "Rnm1_list" inside the loop "for a in range(2):" , otherwise you will append the values to the same list over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange as follows and call the function `Rnm_1()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Rnm_1(c1,c2,a1,a2):
    Rnm1_list =[]
    for n in range(-1,2):
        for m in range(-1,2):
            Rnm1= c1 + (n*a1+m*a2)
            Rnm1_list.append(Rnm1)
    return Rnm1_list

coordsA=[]
for a in range(2):
    c1= np.array([0,0])
    c2= np.array([a,0])
    a1= np.array([3/2*a,3**0.5/2*a])
    a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3**0.5/2*a])
    coordsA.append(Rnm_1(c1,c2,a1,a2))

print(coordsA)
```